# .htaccess - masking url to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url, browser, subdomain

So we have people typing in a browser:

- domain.com/es
- domain.com/es/name-1
- domain.com/es/...

I would like it to be forwarded to and masked:

- es.domain.com
- es.domain.com/name-1
- es.domain.com/...

What I want is - if I named it correctly - people type and see in their browser *domain.com/es/...* all the time and in fact it works as *es.domain.com/...* but they do not know it.

I have also www to non-www basic re-wirte rule. I hope this is not a problem.

Is there a problem for seo or google with such masking?

Comment: "people typing in a browser" - But what's the canonical URL? Surely the subdomain is canonical (otherwise what's the point of having a subdomain)?

Comment: no, canonical is "domain.com/es", I would like not to promote "es.domain.com" at all but because I have different stores and it needs to work on different subdomains - I cannot avoid subdomains - these subdomains is only for the system, no one should know that "domain.com/es" is in fact "es.domain.com"